# How to solve "TypeError: invoker is not a function" in Jest test case?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ramda.js, babel-jest

I ran the test using ramda with jest and I am getting the following error.

Error code
I don't know why, but the pointer appears on line 7, floor method probably has nothing to do with it.

```
> jest_sample@1.0.0 test /app
> jest

 FAIL  Tests/Utils/StringUtils.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: invoker is not a function

       5 |   if (!Number.isFinite(num)) return '';
       6 |
    >  7 |   const intValue = num > 0 ? Math.floor(num) : Math.ceil(num);
         |                                     ^
       8 |
       9 |   const decimalStr = String(num).indexOf('.') > -1 ? `.${String(num).split('.')[1]}` : '';
      10 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ramda/src/join.js:27:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/StringUtil.js:7:37)
      at Object.<anonymous> (Tests/Utils/StringUtils.test.js:1:2)
```

Here is the relevant code where the error occurred.

src

```
import R from 'ramda';

export const commize = num => {
  if (!Number.isFinite(num)) return '';

  const intValue = num > 0 ? Math.floor(num) : Math.ceil(num);

  const decimalStr = String(num).indexOf('.') > -1 ? `.${String(num).split('.')[1]}` : '';

  const intStr = R.pipe(Math.abs, R.toString, R.split(''), R.reverse, R.splitEvery(3), R.intersperse(','), R.flatten, R.reverse, R.join(''));
  return num < 0 ? `-${intStr(intValue)}${decimalStr}` : `${intStr(intValue)}${decimalStr}`;
};
```

test code

```
 import {
  commize,
} from '../../app/StringUtil';

test('commize', () => {
  expect(commize(123456)).toEqual('123,456');
  expect('123').toEqual(commize(123));
  expect('23,456').toEqual(commize(23456));
});
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
    '@babel/preset-flow',
  ],
  plugins: [
  ],
  env: {
    test: {
      presets: [
        '@babel/preset-react',
        ['@babel/preset-env', {
          modules: false,
        }],
      ],
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        'ramda',
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

I've tried the following, but it didn't work.

- I have changed the babel settings, referring to the [official documentation](https://github.com/ramda/ramda#usage)

If you know how to fix the problem, please let me know. Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: The question title does not match the actual error: `lift` ≠ `invoker`. Which is it? And does the error really point to the middle `o` of the `floor` function?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The title was incorrect and has been corrected.

Comment: `does the error really point to the middle o of the floor function?`
I don't know why, but the pointer appears on line 7. I added a new line and checked, but the pointer appears where it is not floor. @Thomas

Comment: I suspect that the pointer is bogus, and the actual error happens at `node_modules/ramda/src/join.js:27:1`, where we do indeed see `invoker`. I suspect it has something to do with the build system and how imports are processed, but I have no time to investigate further.

Comment: It seems to work fine [in the REPL](http://link.fourwindssoft.com/72)